# How can i create a form in system.xml

Tags: magento2

I need to create a form in system.xml having username and password field on submitting it should need to append one more field license key is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

please refer to this article maybe this helps

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/create-system-xml-configuration-magento-2.html

Comment: there is not mentioned how to create form in system.xml

Comment: as you can create a single field you can create all field that look like form ........ because in config you dont need to save any of the field magneto will automatically save it upon save click

Comment: No i need a separate form which calls an api